# Box API Slow Search Performance

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

We have an enterprise Box account with about 17k files.  Using the [search endpoint](https://developer.box.com/v2.0/reference#searching-for-content) it takes about 5-6 seconds to retrieve the first set of results from the query (see below).

https://api.box.com/2.0/search?query=fees&file_extensions=pdf&content_types=file_content&type=file&limit=200&offset=0

Can anything be done to improve the performance, or is that a typical response time?  I noticed when using the Box website (see below), it appears much quicker 2-3 seconds.

https://app.box.com/folder/0/search?query=fees&pageSize=20&sortDirection=desc&types=pdf&kinds=file_content&metadata=&folderID=0

In addition, in the website search results there is an extract with highlighting, is that possible through the API?  Is there a field that can be requested with this information?

**EDIT** - I was was able to improve the time slightly by using the fields parameter, but it was still 4-5 seconds to retrieve the first 200 matches.

fields=name,size,path_collection,created_at,modified_at

Comment: Were you able to find any solution to slow search performance?

Comment: @ChuckNorris Unfortunately not, we abandoned using the API for FTS.  We decided to create our own external index as the performance was dramatically faster and with more control.  We are now looking into migrating over to either PostgreSQL or ElasticSearch.